# Firebase push notification: display notification using flutter_local_notifications while app is in background/ terminated

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I want to display push notification using *flutter_local_notifications* while app is in **opened/background/terminated**. Usually we display foreground notification using any package like flutter_local_notifications or awesome notification and display background/terminated state notification from firebase default notification as firebase don't show foreground notification. *How to override firebase background/terminate state notification using flutter_local_notifications?* I've tried calling showNotification(message)- showing using flutter_local_notifications like below

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
```

```
void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
  if(message == null) return;
  showNotification(message);
}
```

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage msg) async {
  if(msg.notification != null) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
}
```

```
Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
 // added flutter_local_notifications code here.
}
```

But this ain't show local notification view with action buttons. Its only showing firebase notification view while app is in background/terminated.
**Need help for how I could display firebase background/terminated state notification using flutter_local_notifications**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

So notification messages are handled by the system automatically. This means that when you're app is backgrounded, they are displayed by the system.

If you always want to handle the display in your own application code, you should send data-only messages - so without a `notification` property in them.